# how to send remote form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have a form which is using several input fields being ajaxified with `remote: true` and custom controller actions. This way UJS driver sends only given form input as params. What I want to accomplish is an ajaxified input field which will send value of a field outside of it's "scope" as `params`. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the whole flow of the ajax-rails and remote=> true and you can do this with that following way and you can get all the params in your method.

first when you used the remote=> true then the form will submit or call the action which you have define in form like here is an example:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'my', :action => 'my_data'},:id => 'filter_form', :remote => true) do %>
 #code here
<%= submit_tag 'save', :name => 'commit'%>
<%end%>
```

now above code will go to my_data action in my controller,

here you can define the respone type with

```
def my_data
#actions on data here
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
```

now you have to made a .js file with named as action name....

```
my_data.js.erb
```

here the whole affect of form you can write and update document element through jquery and javascript.

For every input you just assign a class and write a method that call when the input box will change.One more thing that when you wants to do in a single method the every input have a unique ID, send that also in params and do task what ever you wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Rails' JQuery UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) is just a dependency which Rails uses to call `ajax` requests on your behalf. This means your question is not particularly to do with JQuery UJS, but with how to handle it with ajax overall

You'll typically handle any extra data by appending it to the Ajax request:

```
<%= link_to "Link", new_post_path(params: "here"), remote: true %>
```

If you want to create an "ajaxified" field, you'll probably have to use a manual ajax call to capture the `change` event, allowing you to send the data to your event:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$('input[name="element"]').on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
});
```

Then, as mentioned by `@baharat Soni`, you'll be able to handle the request on the server using `respond_to`